A ServerEndpoint/WebSocket pair works on local Tomcat but not in Heroku
I have this Java WebSocket application here. My code for constructing the URL for the server endpoint is:
function constructWebSocket(endpoint, onMessageCallback) {

    const url = constructWebSocketUrl(endpoint);
    const socket = new WebSocket(url);

    socket.onopen = (event) => {
        console.log("onopen. Event: ", event);
    };

    socket.onmessage = onMessageCallback;
    socket.onclose = (event) => {
        console.log("onclose. Event: ", event);
    };

    socket.onerror = (event) => {
        console.log("onerror. Event: ", event);
    };

    return socket;
}

function constructWebSocketUrl(endpoint) {
    const host = document.location.host;
    const path = document.location.pathname;
    const protocol = document.location.protocol;
    
    if (protocol.startsWith("https")) {
        return `wss://${host}${path}${endpoint}`;
    } else if (protocol.startsWith("http")) {
        return `ws://${host}${path}${endpoint}`;
    } else {
        throw `Unknown protocol: ${protocol}.`;
    }
}

(The app is deployed on Heroku.)
While the above snippet returns a valid WebSocket when I run the web app on local Tomcat, on Heroku it returns 404 Not Found and close code 1006. What am I missing here?
Logs
When I try to call to a \randomize WebSocket, in logs there is the following error message apended:
2024-04-12T10:31:55.096386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/randomize" host=wiki-game-killer-ae0862952895.herokuapp.com request_id=bd425c43-f582-4152-ad24-3f7ee429ca88 fwd="93.106.179.198" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=854 protocol=https


Can you check the url appending right or not

Why defining constructWebSocketURL twice? And why adding path?
function constructWebSocketUrl(endpoint) {
    const host = document.location.host;
    // Removed the `path` as it might be causing the issue by adding unnecessary segments to the URL
    const protocol = document.location.protocol;
    
    if (protocol.startsWith("https")) {
        return `wss://${host}/${endpoint}`;
    } else if (protocol.startsWith("http")) {
        return `ws://${host}/${endpoint}`;
    } else {
        throw `Unknown protocol: ${protocol}.`;
    }
}


@VonC Removed the duplicate of constructWebSocketUrl. Also, I made sure that after creating each WebSocket, onopen, onmessage, onclose and onerror are set only once. (Previously, I have set all but onmessage twice.) However, the same bug persists.

Can u also post Heroku logs?

@subdeveloper Ready!

The problem was simply Java (JDK) version mismatch. After I forced all the involved (3) projects to rely on the same JDK 20, WebSocket started to work.
Also, I needed to follow these instructions.

I'm not a Java/Heroku deployment expert, but I suspect this 404 could be because you're trying to access Web Socket. Can you:
Try commenting and uncommenting this from your pom.xml:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.websocket-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
       <!--        
         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        
    
         https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.30</version>-->
        <!--</dependency>
        -->


     <!-- truncated - subdeveloper -->

  </dependencies>



Then make your procfile like this:
web: java -jar myapp-ws/target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/WikiGameKillerWebApp.java-1.0.0.war

I see a packaging type as war in your pom.xml, so this should work.
In case it does not work, try including web-runner like mentioned here or here.
For more details see: Deploying Tomcat-based Java Web Applications with Webapp Runner

Your answer was the closest match.

Couple thoughts:
(1) Are you following these steps to launch an embedded tomcat on Heroku? How are you launching your Java application in Heroku?
(2) Have you tried one of the examples with websockets like Node/Go I know you have dependencies on other Java projects so that wouldn't necessarily help you at the end, but it might help elucidate what's different in the Tomcat setup vs. other languages.
